# Error:Element type "shape" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#A1887F"
        android:endColor="#4E342E"
        android:angle="90"
        android:type="linear"
        />

    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"
        />

    <stroke
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:width="3dp"
        />
</shape>
```

When I compile this code and I am getting an error As I mentioned on the title . What is the error of the above code ?

Comment: Is this your full XML? Where's the `shape` element it is referring to?

Comment: Can you post the section where you have declared your shape element?